# Teradata-jdbc: What's the point of using Fastload if java has memory limitations?

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

Here is the link to a sample jdbc Fastload program from the teradata website :  http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20205JD.java.txt

It inserts only one row so I modified it to insert 500K rows by replacing the following code  :

```
                        pstmt.setInt(1, 1);
                        pstmt.setString(2, strBuf);
                        pstmt.addBatch();
                        batchCount++;
```

with :

```
                        for (int i = 0; i < 500000 ; i ++ ) {
                        pstmt.setInt(1, i);
                        pstmt.setString(2, strBuf);
                        pstmt.addBatch();
                        batchCount++;
                        }
```

It of course failed because java was out of memory.

So Fastloads jdbc fails to    upload EVEN  500K rows of very simple data  . .  because the method `addBatch()`    throws `outOfMemory` exception at some point.

But  I read that Fastload was able to upload millions of rows ! ! ! However I could not find any real example anywhere . How to overcome `outOfMemory` java exception ?

**Can anybody show an example with `jdbc` and `Fastload` (NOT FastloadCSV!) to upload let's say 1M rows ?**

---

PS :

1) `xmx` increase of heap space defeats the purpose, because every additional `addBatch()` methods executes slower, and additional heap has limitations ( usually 4 g )

2) I do not need `FastloadCSV` , because it does not support text qualifiers until ttu 14 and has other issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must `setAutoCommit(false)` and then simply `executeBatch` multiple times, e.g. after every 50,00 or 100,000 `addBatch`, before you run out of memory. Finally you `commit`.

See [Speed up your JDBC/ODBC applications](https://support.teradata.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=b8bb87631bd7fb00682ca8233a4bcb61) on developer.teradata.com

Comment: You beat me to the suggestion! +1 for you, sir.

Comment: +1 Thank you. But after the first `executeBatch` the table is no longer empty, right ? But Fastload is supposed to be used with empty tables only , right ?

Comment: Empty at the begin of the FastLoad, it ends when you commit. That's why you have to switch AutoCommit off.

Comment: Thank you . It works perfect. I have a follow up concern though : Does one need to limit the number of rows added for each batch to 16,383 rows in the `type=fastload` connection ? (I know that for a simple `prepared statement` batch insert  . . every batch should be limited to 16,383 . )  Does this rule hold for the `fastload` in my example above ? Thanks

Comment: The limit of 16,383 is only for standard connections, for `type=fastload` the limit is JVM memory. I added a link to a short article on Teradata's developer exchange.